# Postgres installation on minikube not able to persist data

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have deployed postgres db into kubernetes using minikube. I have also mounted a directory from my local system using the following command

```
minikube start -p sandbox
minikube -p sandbox mount /home/mrrobot/Volumes:/mnt/data --port=39189
```

I also checked the permission of the mounted folder using the following commands:

```
minikube -p sandbox ssh
ls -al /mnt/data
```

i can see that it has the right permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 docker docker 4096 Jan 16 11:07
```

I created a postgres deployment spec yaml and the necessary volumes required and everything started running. But when i restart minikube after sometime i do not see the user that i created earlier. I do not think anything is being persisted into the volume that i specified. I have to create the user and the database again from the start every time i stop and start minikube again.

This is the postgres deployment specification file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: sandbox
  labels:
    environment: Development
    name: PostgresDeployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: PostgresPOD
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postgres-pod
      labels:
        name: PostgresPOD
        environment: Development
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres-db
        image: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: postgres-db-secret
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: "512Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: "1024Mi"
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pvc
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  namespace: sandbox
  labels:
    name:  postgres-pv
    environment: Development
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  hostPath:
    path:  /mnt/data
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  namespace: sandbox
  labels:
    name: postgres-pvc
    environment: Development
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

I do not see any errors in the pod logs and postgres seems to be running fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w71Qt.png)

Can someone help me figure out why when i stop and start minikube again after sometime. The user that i had created earlier is not available?

I also tried converting it to a statefull set and that also did not work.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: sandbox
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: postgres-service
  replicas: 1 # by default is 1
  minReadySeconds: 10 # by default is 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: postgres-db-secret
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-volume
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: postgres-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      storageClassName: standard
      volumeMode: Filesystem
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Minikube has [its own storage provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi).  What happens if you delete the manual PersistentVolume/Claim, change the Deployment to a StatefulSet, and rely on the cluster to manage storage?

Comment: It did not work. i have updated the description